# when i run command 'npm i react-navigation-drawer' it show errror help me

Tags: react-native

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: gamezone1@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react-native-gesture-handler@2.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler
npm ERR!   react-native-gesture-handler@"~2.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-gesture-handler@"^1.0.12" from react-navigation-drawer@2.7.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-navigation-drawer
npm ERR!   react-navigation-drawer@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full
report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-04T05_25_21_285Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 1):

try this,
`npm i react-navigation-drawer --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: I run this command it runs successfully . now I have to run the command 'npm i react-navigation drawer' or not

Comment: no need to run `npm i react-navigation drawer` again